# Prove there exists a unique continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

suppose that $f:A\to\mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous on $A$. Let $\overline{A}$ be the closure of $A$.

Assuming that there exists a continuous extension of $f$,

$g:\overline{A}\to \mathbb R$ s.t. for all $x \in A, g(x)=f(x)$

prove that the extension is unique.

I'm fairly certain that I have to assume that there are two functions, say $g$ and $g'$, and somehow conclude that they are actually the same function. I'm quite confused as how to go further. Any suggestions or help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $h$ is a continuous extension of $f$ to $\bar{A}$ so that $f(x)=h(x)$ on $A$.  We want to show that $h(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in \bar{A}$.

Let $y$ be any element in $\bar{A}\setminus A$.  Since $y\in \bar{A}$ there exists a sequence $(y_{n})\to y$ where each $y_{n}\in A$.  Since $h$ is continuous, $\lim_{n\to\infty} h(y_n)=h(y)$.  Similarly, $\lim_{n\to\infty}g(y_n)=g(y)$.  Since every $y_n$ is in $A$ it follows that $g(y_n)=h(y_n)$ for all $n$.  Hence, the limits of the sequences are the same.  I.e. $g(y)=h(y)$.  Since this is true for all $y\in \bar{A}\setminus A$ it follows that $g=h$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another, more general, proof that works in any Hausdorff space.

**Proposition:** Let $X$ be any topological space, and let $Y$ be a Hausdorff space. Suppose $A \subset X$ is dense in $X$, and that $f: A \to Y$ is a continuous map which extends continuously to some map $\bar{f}:X \to Y$. Then $\bar{f}$ is the **unique** extension of $f$ to $X$ which is continuous.

**Proof:** Suppose that the claim is false, so that the map $f$ admits two different continuous extensions $g \neq h$. Choose $x \in X$ such that $g(x) \neq h(x)$. Since $Y$ is Hausdorff, we can find disjoint neighborhoods $U$ and $V$ such that $g(x) \in U$ and $h(x) \in V$. Since $g$ and $h$ are continuous it follows that $g^{-1}(U) \cap h^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$. Also $g^{-1}(U) \cap h^{-1}(V)$ is nonempty since it contains $x$. Since $A$ is assumed to be dense in $X$, we can deduce that $g^{-1}(U) \cap h^{-1}(V) \cap A$ is nonempty. Choose a point $a \in g^{-1}(U) \cap h^{-1}(V) \cap A$. Then $f(a)=g(a)=h(a) \in U \cap V$, which contradicts the fact that $U$ and $V$ are disjoint. $\Box$

**Note:** The above proposition is false if we do not assume that $Y$ is Hausdorff. For example, let $X$ be the real line with the usual topology. Let $A=\mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}$, which is clearly dense in $X$. Let $Y$ be the real line with the cofinite topology (this is the topology where the closed sets are the finite sets). Then the map $f: X \to Y$ given by $x \mapsto |x|$ admits uncountably many different continuous extensions. Namely $\bar{f}(0)$ can be any real number.